# Wordpress Text Widget Links

Tags: wordpress, text, hyperlink, widget

I am adding text links to a wordpress text widget that goes in the sidebar of my site.

I am adding the example link here wrapped in a "a href":

```
<a href=“http://www.instagram.com” target="_blank">Instagram</a>
```

but when the link is clicked, it opens a url that contains my site's url in front of the linked url. For example:

http://mysiteurl.com/www.instagram.com/

I can't figure out why this is happening as this is usually the most simple adjustment for a site.

Thank you,

Comment: The link that you are entering into the widget is `<a href="http://instagram.com/" target="_blank">` right?

Comment: sorry the Stack Overflow is erasing the http:// in my links

Comment: In your post you have `“`, try replace them with `"`

Comment: Thank you for the help, turned out it was the difference of the quotations, from “, to "

Thank you Howlin and everyone else who helped me answer this question!

Kaden

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure "http://" is in your href ?
It happends when your href="www.instagram.com"
Good : href="http://www.instagram.com"

Comment: yeah, my links are formatted like this, <a href=“http://www.instagram.com” target="_blank">Instagram</a> which seems normal to me

Comment: Thank you for the help, turned out it was the difference of the quotations, from “, to "

Thank you Howlin and everyone else who helped me answer this question!

Kaden

Answer (score 0):

You are linking to "`instagram.com`" rather than `http://instagram.com`.

Your browser needs a protocol (`http://`) in order to know what to do with the link.  If there is no protocol it assumes the link is local to the site you're on, so navigates you there.

If you include the protocol, your browser will know it is a separate entity and navigate to the correct place.

The full link should look like:

`<a href="http://instagram.com" target="_blank">Instagram</a>`

Answer (score 0):

What was causing the issue was that `“` quotes were used instead of `"`. So the correct link is

```
<a href="http://instagram.com/" target="_blank">Instagram</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href=“http://www.instagram.com” target="_blank">Instagram</a>
```